# "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" in .net core 6 Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

Hello I'm trying to run the below query in.net core 6 and oracle DB but an exception throw ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended error

```
_entity.atms.Where(p => p.Atmid == atmId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Please help

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you enable logging (if you haven't already) and include the logged SQL query this produces?

Comment: Make sure the database is still in the state you expect it to be in. Most likely, you configured code first without running a migration, or someone changed the database without your knowledge.

Comment: Hi @Zulqarnain, could you pls share more code? What is your `_entity` and how is your DbContext? Also can you check the Output panel what is the sql query this linq generated?